# C++ No Instance of Constructor matches the argument list Error

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm getting a error on VS.

> C++ no instance of constructor matches the argument list argument types are: (const char [11], int, const char [3], const char [10])

I'm not allowed to change main.cpp and I've been given the function prototypes beforehand. I'm having trouble with the constructors. These are the requirements:

> **Constructors**
>
> The HeathCard can either get created with no values (default constructor) into a safe empty state or use all four values.
>
> Instead of overloading the constructor you can use one constructor with the default values for the four parameters, (i.e nullptr, 0, {}, {} ) and remember to reuse the **set** function for the latter case.
>
> Note that since the **m_name** attribute is initialized in the class definition to be **nullptr**, there is no need to worry about setting it to **nullptr** before calling the set function.
>
> Rule of three
>
> **Copy Constructor**
> `HeathCard(const HeathCard& hc);`
>
> - if the **hc** object is valid it will set the values of the current object to those of the incoming argument (**hc** using assignment to *this).
>
> **Copy Assignment operator overload**
> `HeathCard& operator=(const HeathCard& hc);`
>
> - First, it will make sure that this is not a "self-copy" by comparing the address of the current object and the address of the incoming argument.
>
>   - If it is not a self copy this function works exactly like the copy constructor
> - If it is a self copy don't perform any action
>   At the end return the reference of the current object.
>
> **Destructor**
>
> deletes the memory pointed by **m_name**.

```
#define  _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring> 
#include "HealthCard.h"
using namespace std; 

namespace sdds { 
    
 
    HealthCard::HealthCard(const char* name, long long number, const char vCode, const char sNumber)
    {
        set(name, number, vCode, sNumber); 
    }

    bool HealthCard::validID(const char* name, long long number, const char vCode, const char sNumber) const {
        return m_name != nullptr && m_name != '\0' && vCode != '\0' && sNumber != '\0' && number > 999999999 && number < 9999999999;
    }

    void HealthCard::setEmpty() {
        delete[] m_name;
        m_name = nullptr; 
        m_number = 0; 
        m_vCode[3] = '\0';   
        m_sNumber[10] = '\0'; 
    }

    ////////////////////////
    void HealthCard::allocateAndCopy(const char* name) {
        delete[] m_name;
        m_name = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
        strcpy(m_name, name);
    }

    void HealthCard::extractChar(std::istream& istr, char ch) const {
        char chinput;
        chinput = istr.peek();
        if (chinput == ch) {
            ch = istr.get();
            //istr.get(); //removes dssk? istr.ignore()
        }
        else {
            istr.setstate(ios::failbit);
        }
    }

    std::ostream& HealthCard::printIDInfo(std::ostream& ostr) const {
        ostr << "(";
        ostr << m_number;
        ostr << "-";
        ostr << m_vCode;
        ostr << ", ";
        ostr << m_sNumber; 
        ostr.width(4);
        ostr.fill('0');
        ostr.setf(ios::left);
        ostr.unsetf(ios::left);
        
        return ostr;

    }

    void HealthCard::set(const char* name, long long number, const char vCode, const char sNumber) {
        if (name != nullptr && name[0] && validID(name, number, vCode, sNumber)) { 
            allocateAndCopy(name);
            m_number = number;  
            m_vCode[3] = vCode; 
            m_sNumber[10] = sNumber;  
        } 
        else {
            setEmpty();
        }
    }

    HealthCard::HealthCard() {
        setEmpty();
    }

    HealthCard::HealthCard(const HealthCard& hc) {
        if (hc) {
            set(hc.m_name, hc.m_number, hc.m_vCode[3], hc.m_sNumber[10]);
        }
        else {
            setEmpty();
        }
    }

    HealthCard& HealthCard::operator=(const HealthCard& hc) {
        if (this != &hc) {
            set(hc.m_name, hc.m_number, hc.m_vCode[3], hc.m_sNumber[10]);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    HealthCard::~HealthCard() {
        delete[] m_name;
    }

    HealthCard::operator bool() const {
        return m_name != nullptr && m_name[0]; 
    }

    std::ostream& HealthCard::print(std::ostream& ostr, bool toFile = true) const {

        if (operator bool())
        {
            if (toFile)
            {
                ostr.width(50);
                ostr.fill('.');
                ostr.setf(ios::left);
                ostr << m_name;
                printIDInfo(ostr); 
                ostr.unsetf(ios::left);
            }
            else
            {
                ostr.width(50);
                ostr.fill('.');
                ostr.setf(ios::left);
                ostr << m_name;
                printIDInfo(ostr);
                ostr.unsetf(ios::left);
            }
        }
        else

            ostr << "Invalid Phone Record";
        return ostr;
    }

    std::istream& HealthCard::read(std::istream& istr) {
        //Luke Skywalker,(647) 555-9475
        char name[MaxNameLength];
        int number;
        char vCode;
        char sNumber; 


        istr.get(name, MaxNameLength, ',');
        extractChar(istr, ',');
        if (istr.fail())
        {
            return istr;
        }
        
        istr >> number; 

        extractChar(istr, '-');
        if (istr.fail())
        {
            return istr;
        }
        //extractChar(istr, ' ');
        istr >> vCode;
        if (istr.fail())
        {
            return istr;
        }
        extractChar(istr, ','); 
        istr >> sNumber;

        if (istr.fail())
        {
            return istr;
        }
        extractChar(istr, '\n');
        if (istr.fail())
        {
            return istr;
        }
        set(name, number, vCode, sNumber);

        return istr;
    }


    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostr, const HealthCard& cnt) {
        return cnt.print(ostr, false);

    }

    std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& istr, HealthCard& cnt) {
        return cnt.read(istr);
    }





}
```

```
#ifndef SDDS_HEALTHCARD_H
#define SDDS_HEALTHCARD_H
#include <iostream> 

namespace sdds {

    const int MaxNameLength = 55;

    class HealthCard {
        char* m_name{};
        long long m_number;
        char m_vCode[3];
        char m_sNumber[10]; 

        void setEmpty();
        void allocateAndCopy(const char* name);
        bool validID(const char* name, long long number, const char vCode, const char sNumber) const; //return true
        void extractChar(std::istream& istr, char ch) const;
        std::ostream& printIDInfo(std::ostream& ostr) const; 
        void set(const char* name, long long number, const char vCode, const char sNumber);

    public:
        HealthCard(); 
        HealthCard(const char* name, long long number, const char vCode, const char sNumber);
        HealthCard(const HealthCard& hc);// Copy 
        HealthCard& operator=(const HealthCard& hc);// Copy Assingment
        ~HealthCard();//Destructor
        operator bool() const; //Returns true if m_name is not null, else it will return false;
        std::ostream& print(std::ostream& ostr, bool) const; 
        std::istream& read(std::istream& istr); 

    };

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostr, const HealthCard& cnt);

    std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& istr, HealthCard& cnt); 




} 
#endif
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "HealthCard.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace sdds;

int noOfRecs(const char* filename);
void showFile(const char* filename);
HealthCard ReadCardFromFile(istream& istr);
void dataEntryTest();
void validationTest();


int main() {
    int i;
    int recs = noOfRecs("HealthCardInfo.csv");
    HealthCard C{ "Gandalf The Grey",111,"XL","123234LA" };
    ifstream CardFile("HealthCardInfo.csv");
    ofstream goodCardFile("goodInfo.csv");
    validationTest();
    dataEntryTest();
    for (i = 0; i < recs; i++) {
        C = ReadCardFromFile(CardFile);
        cout << C << endl;
        if (CardFile)
            C.print(goodCardFile, true);
    }
    if (i == recs)
        cout << "\nAll records were read successfully!" << endl;
    else {
        cout << "Read " << i - 1 << " out of " << recs << " Records successfully" << endl;
        cout << "Record number " << i << " is invalid!" << endl;
    }
    goodCardFile.close();
    showFile("goodInfo.csv");
    return 0;
}


void validationTest() {
    int i;
    HealthCard C[]{
       {"Fred Soley", 1234567890,"AB","WQ1234567"},
       {nullptr, 1234567890,"AB","WQ1234567" },
       {"Fred Soley", 123456789,"B","WQ1234567" },
       {"Fred Soley", 1234567890,"AB","WQ123456" },
       {"Fred Soley", 1234567890,"AB","WQ1234567" },
       {"Fred Soley", 234567890,"AB","Q1234567" },
       {"Fred Soley", 234567890,"B","WQ1234567" },
       {"Fred Soley", 1234567890,"B","Q1234567" },
    };
    cout << "Validation Test" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; cout << C[i++] << endl);
}

int noOfRecs(const char* filename) {
    int num = 0;
    ifstream file(filename);
    while (file) num += (file.get() == '\n');
    return num;
}

void showFile(const char* filename) {
    ifstream file(filename);
    char ch;
    cout << "Contents of " << filename << endl << "----------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    while (file.get(ch)) {
        cout << ch;
    }
}

void dataEntryTest() {
    HealthCard C{ "Fred Soley", 1234567890,"AB","WQ123456" };
    cout << endl << "Data entry test." << endl;
    cout << "Enter the test data using copy and paste to save time:" << endl << endl;

    cout << "Enter the following:" << endl
        << ">Person Name,1231231234-XL,AF1234567" << endl << ">";
    cin >> C;

    cout << "HealthCard Content:" << endl << C << endl;

    cout << "Enter the following:" << endl
        << ">Person Name,1231231234-XL,AF123456" << endl << ">";
    cin >> C;
    cout << "HealthCard Content:" << endl << C << endl;

    cout << "Enter the following:" << endl
        << ">Person Name,1231231234-L,AF1234567" << endl << ">";
    cin >> C;
    cout << "HealthCard Content:" << endl << C << endl;

    cout << "Enter the following:" << endl
        << ">Person Name,1231231234-,AF1234567" << endl << ">";
    cin >> C;
    cout << "HealthCard Content:" << endl << C << endl;

    cout << "Enter the following:" << endl
        << ">Person Name,131231234-XL,AF1234567" << endl << ">";
    cin >> C;
    cout << "HealthCard Content:" << endl << C << endl;

    cout << "Enter the following:" << endl
        << ">Person Name 1231231234-XL,AF1234567" << endl << ">";
    cin >> C;
    cout << "HealthCard Content:" << endl << C << endl;
}


HealthCard ReadCardFromFile(istream& istr) {
    HealthCard C;
    istr >> C;
    return C;
}
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [mre] for the error and copy-paste the complete error message into the question.

Comment: at least highlight the line that gets the error

Comment: Your compiler is right. You are attempting to invoke a constructor with string constants as the last two parameters, but I don't see a matching constructor, just one with `char` (no pointer) parameters as the last two.

Comment: ok, do I change it to string? I've been given this function prototype void set(const char* name, long long number, const char vCode[], const char sNumber[]); Would I have to change it here too?

Comment: Neither your constructor nor your `set` function matches that prototype. `const char` and `const char []` are two very different things. Don't just change function signatures to get rid of compiler errors. Determine what your functions are supposed to do, then declare/define your functions accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming its this line

```
HealthCard C{ "Gandalf The Grey",111,"XL","123234LA" };
```

your constructor is this

```
HealthCard::HealthCard(const char* name, long long number, const char vCode, const char sNumber)
```

can you spot the difference? "XL" is that a char?

Comment: Oh, should it be "string vCode, string sNumber"?

Comment: I've been given this function prototype ```void set(const char* name, long long number, const char vCode[], const char sNumber[]);``` Would I have to change it here too?

Comment: Your constructor does not match that: `HealthCard::HealthCard(const char* name, long long number, const char vCode, const char sNumber)`.   `const char foo` is not `const char foo[]`

Comment: @coder2000 well you should be using string everywhere in c++. But your first arg "Gandalf the gray" is declared as char*name so at least use that.